# Can Carbon Copy Cloner still produce bootable clones?

Tags: macos, backup, startup

According to their web site, Carbon Copy Cloner can produce bootable clones of your internal hard drive.  However I downloaded it, and NO WHERE in the user interface, and NO WHERE in the help documentation does it have any information on this.  What's up?

Did Carbon Copy Cloner remove the ability to produce bootable clones?  Do they simply do it automatically without you having to make any choice?

Comment: Would they be able to tell you if you asked them?

Comment: @SolarMike: when you say "Would they be able to tell you if you asked them?", is that an honest question or a sarcastic remark?  If it's an honest question, I don't know what would make them unable to tell me, so I don't know why you asked.  If it's a sarcastic remark, what value does posting it offer?  Do you think it's helpful?

Answer (score 3):

The information is here [Creating legacy bootable copies of macOS (Big Sur and later)](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc6/cloning-macos-system-volumes-apple-software-restore).

Note the word "legacy". Bootable clones are no longer supported (or supportable). The linked page says:

- we can only offer "best effort" support for making an external bootable device.

The long support article explains the why bootable clones:

- may no longer be useful,
- are difficult to make,
- nearly impossible to update, and
- how to create one so long as you accept all the restrictions.

There may be times when a bootable clone is useful, but for your regular automated backup don't try to make the backup bootable.